Single-Ended Equivalent Circuit for a fully-differential opamp circuit
I have a question regarding the single-ended equivalent circuit for a fully-differential-opamp-based circuit.
This is a fully-differential-opamp-based circuit:
The opamp has a voltage gain of A0 and the two resistors have the values of R.

If I were to draw the single-ended equivalent circuit for the above fully-differential-opamp-based circuit. How should the new values for R1', R2', A' be so that the single-ended circuit is equivalent to the original fully-differential version?

Thank you very much

Resistors should be equal. Note that a simple opamp amplifier has 2 inputs.

@Antonio51  Thank you very much for your reply. I draw the opamp this way to imply that Vo = -A * Vi.  (Vi is the input of the opamp). Hence, the non-inverting input is already assumed ac gnd.   How about the A' value?  Should it be half the original A0 or equal to A0?

I think this does not matter ... A is generally something like 1e6 or more.

Thank you very much for your help :)  I will digest the idea and have a think about it some more :)

It's important to understand what "equal" means. Does it mean the same Gain?
It will not mean the same noise performance, etc.
First of all, the gain of both circuits will be defined by resistors, provided that the selected gain is set to be smaller then Gain (A0 and A') of the amplifier. This might seem very logical "always true", but it has to be true for ALL FREQUENCIES that are required. Differential amplifiers have sometimes much higher GBW. If one amplifier has GBW =1MHz and the other 10MHz and you set the gain of both to 1, you will get very different frequency response. Well, actually gain of the first will fall under 1 at 1MHz and Gain of the latter at 10MHz in this case. But apart from this, Gain itself doesn't matter.
If we talk about the resistors that will define the gain: I will first assume you need the same gain, then resistors should be the same, provided that for the single ended input Vin+ is connected to ground and net connecting R1 and R2 is connected to Vin-.

Thank you very much for your reply. I'll have a think about the ideas :)
